# gnome-panel custom menu

Tags: gnome-panel, menu, applet

I just reinstalled 10.04 and I can't for the life of me remember how I did this.  I used to have an icon on my panel which, when clicked, would roll out a specific sub-menu found int he main menu.

For example: Whereas I can click Applications > System Tools > VirtualBox > Webserver right now, I used to e able to click the icon on the panel and the Virtualbox menu would pop up out of the icon.  It wasn't a drawer because the items displayed were whatever was in the linked submenu, I did not have to update them both separately.

Any ideas how I got that working before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty non-intuitive, but I remember figuring it out a few times, and I basically remember.

You right click on a menu item in the menu you want, and choose "Entire Menu", then "Add this as menu to panel".

Comment: Brilliant, mate!  Non-intuitive indeed!  I thought I remembered using an applet of some sort to handle it, but that works as I had wanted so none needed.  Thanks for saving what's left of my hair from being torn out.  I can't vote you up yet or I would.

Comment: Glad I could help.  We hair-impaired need to stick together. :)